Unable to import CosmosDb (Mongo) into Azure AI Search
I'm trying to import CosmosDb (Mongo) data into an Azure AI Search service.  I have the Search Service set to allow Azure Services access.  The CosmosDb is set to public access.
I tried using the MongoDb connection string:
mongodb+srv://[user:password]@[service name].mongocluster.cosmos.azure.com/?tls=true&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000
but got error:
Error detecting index schema from data source: "Connection string specified is malformed. Details: Connection string must contain a valid value 'undefined' for the 'AccountEndpoint' property.. Please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086037 for more information."
I also tried this format:
AccountEndpoint=https://[service name].documents.azure.com;AccountKey=[account key];Database=[database]
But was unable to determine where the account key comes from and what the correct endpoint should be.
Anyone know how to import CosmosDB data into the Azure AI Search service?
Thank you

Not sure if you are migrating that data into AI Search for vector search but if you are, there is another Mongo API option in Cosmos (MongoDB vCore) that has native vector search that would allow you to keep data in a database without having to continually ETL it into AI Search.


Unable to import CosmosDb (Mongo) into Azure AI Search

Try with this connection string format:
AccountEndpoint=https://[account_name].documents.azure.com;AccountKey=*****;ApiKind=MongoDB

Data stored in Azure Cosmos Mongo DB API

I used the same connection string format, and the data imported successfully as shown in the output below.


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
